# uiprogressview update issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two views, first one "A", has a button that trigger a web service to validate one code, if validation is successful, it performs a segue to the view "B".

In view B, I have this

```
- (bool) viewDidUpload

   dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{


    [self processContacts];
    [self sendPost];
});



-(void) processContacts

    //Process contact address

-(void) sendPost
    //Process web services call
    //If web service call is OK, call [self updateBar]
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateBar) 
                               withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

UPDATED: I implemented GDC to send sendPost and processContacts in the background, then sendPost method has the updateBar call performed using performSelectorOnMainThread:, the problem is that the execution doesn't enter in this method and it finishes without updating the bar. sendPost and processContacts now run in the background, but I don't know how to perform updateBar in the main every time a valid connection is done, and then return to the background and perform rest of connections and again.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform all calculations and communications in background thread. Then do updates on GUI stuff (like progress bar) in your main thread.

Take a look at GCD. It is really easy to use and will solve your problem I'm sure.

Comment: I have implemented GDC to send to background connection methods, but for instance, if there are 100 connections to done, and update the bar in the main for everyone, I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking here? If you know the number of connections when you start, you use that number to estimate how much is left until the progress bar is full. Then after each connection has finished you call the main thread and update the progress bar (increment a counter or something to keep track on progress).

Answer (score 1):

So seems that you are using internet and best way for me to do so is using the Git library of ASIHTTPRequest, read it and download it then use it, it's very useful, enjoy:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I tried to use it, but I gave me a lot of trouble to use with IOS5, I follow instructions to make it compatible but it wasn't successful. Do you have any information to how make it work with IOS5?

Comment: If you can pinpoint you problem , I will be more than happy to assist you, I guess you have problem with the ARC (Automatic reference count) used in the new xCode where the File of GitHub still are not updated to it, just go the project in xcode, click on the target, go to compile sources , select the HTTP request files double click and add the following : -fno-objc-arc this will make the compiler skip the following files to be ARC compiled.